# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key "student". error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Iam using ASP.Net MVC3 Razor,

I have a controller where i binded the data

```
public Actionresult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.student= new SelectList(db.Collection, "ID", "Name"); 
ViewBag.student1= new SelectList(db.Collection, "ID", "Name"); 
return view(); 
  }
```

This is my view

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    @Html.DropDownList("student")

    </td>
    <td>

    @Html.DropDownList("student1")
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What is the problem in my code, could any one help me ...
Thanx in advance..

Comment: Why don't you use a view model and define that property instead?

Comment: I did that too, but getting the same error.I did like this @Html.dropDownList(model => model.ID, ViewData["student"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select One", new { @id = "ddlstudent" })

Answer (score 0):

```
public Actionresult Index()
{
    ViewBag.studentList = new SelectList(db.Collection, "ID", "Name"); 
    ViewBag.student1List = new SelectList(db.Collection, "ID", "Name"); 
    return view(); 
}

<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    @Html.DropDownList("student", (SelectList)ViewBag.studentList)

    </td>
    <td>

    @Html.DropDownList("student1", (SelectList)ViewBag.student1List)
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @user1603121 You have error in other code. `@Html.DropDownList("student")` - where `student` is just name of the form field. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist%28v=vs.108%29.aspx